# fatal: No HEAD commit to compare with (yet)

Tags: git

I am newbie with git. It tried [this](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gittutorial.html) tutorial, but after the command, i get this error:

```
[root@WL-0022150E7BD4 alma]$ git diff --cached
fatal: No HEAD commit to compare with (yet)
```

I created two file in the current directory. I dont understand, it is the first step in the tutorial.

Comment: No, it isn't. `git add .` followed by `git commit` come before that, and even those aren't the first steps in the tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the first step in the tutorial: you should have done `git init`, `git add .` (with at least some files in the working directory), `git commit` and another `git add` before you do a git `diff --cached`.

Provided that there wasn't an error in the commit step, `git diff --cached` should not give you this error.

Comment: Ok, not the first step, but it is in the first steps. Anyway i solved my problem. 

git commit 

command hadn't any affect cause, first you will use 
git commit -m 'Initial commit' 

type of command. With the -m parameter.

Comment: Unfortunately, in this basic tutorial they forget this to emphasize.

Comment: You don't have to use `-m`, without it you should be able to use a text editor to write a commit message.